# Can not see integer value in constant pool

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Here is simple class.

```
public class Test{
    private int a = 10;
    private float b = 20.0F;
}
```

Using `javap -v -l Test.class` command to see the structure of class file. In `Constant pool` section, I should see all constants of the class. Nevertheless, I can find float value is 20.0f, but can not find int value.

```
public class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#17         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #5.#18         // Test.a:I
   #3 = Float              20.0f
   #4 = Fieldref           #5.#19         // Test.b:F
   #5 = Class              #20            // Test
   #6 = Class              #21            // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               a
   #8 = Utf8               I
   #9 = Utf8               b
  #10 = Utf8               F
  #11 = Utf8               <init>
  #12 = Utf8               ()V
  #13 = Utf8               Code
  #14 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #15 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #16 = Utf8               Test.java
  #17 = NameAndType        #11:#12        // "<init>":()V
  #18 = NameAndType        #7:#8          // a:I
  #19 = NameAndType        #9:#10         // b:F
  #20 = Utf8               Test
  #21 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: bipush        10
         7: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
        10: aload_0
        11: ldc           #3                  // float 20.0f
        13: putfield      #4                  // Field b:F
        16: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
        line 2: 4
        line 3: 10
}
SourceFile: "Test.java"
```

As per the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4-140

I should see `CONSTANT_Integer` in constant pool.

Comment: The constant pool turn a small integer into a more complex value which is especially useful if that value appears more than once in making the code smaller. Small integers don't benefit from this as they are already small integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are special instructions for loading small integer values (`iconst_x` for values from -1 to 5, `bipush x` for byte values and `sipush x` for short values).

The constant pool is only used for integer values outside of this range, i.e. for numbers less than -32768 or greater than 32767.

Comment: Adding to the same, try to run the code with int value more than 32767. You find that value present in the constant pool

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried with 40000. the value present in the constant pool.

Comment: As an addendum, if you declare a real constant, i.e. a `final` field that is immediately initialized with a constant, you’ll always see a matching `CONSTANT_Integer` in the pool.